# selenium ide menu bar missing in linux OS

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, selenium, menubar

I am a selenium newbie trying to install selenium ide on my Ubuntu.

This is how i installed - 
1. Open Firefox Browser
2. Goto http://seleniumhq.org/download/
3. Click on Download Version 1.9.0
4. Install and Restart Firefox
5. Click on Tools, find Selenium IDE and click to start.

Issue with Selenium IDE -

Selenium IDE is not installed properly, because I see no Menu Bar(File, Edit, Options, Help) when I open the selenium ide. So there is no way I can save, rename etc or access other functions.

Versions that I am using - Ubuntu 12.0.4, Firefox 14.0.1, Selenium ide 1.9.0.

Please let me know if I am not installing ide properly.

I appreciate all tips and pointers on how to fix this or any work around.  Also please let me know if you find any information vague or need any more specific details about this issue.

Thanks for your time

Puvi

P.S - I tried uploading a screenshot of Selenium ide with missing menu bar, however, stakoverflow does not let new members upload images till they earn 10 reputations points!!

Answer (score 6):

You can find the menu options on the browser menu itself. Just roll your mouse point over the menu bar of the browser while Selenium IDE's window is opened.
Instead of Firefox's menu options it will show Selenium IDE's Menu options...

Comment: That is cool. Thanks for your time. I had a copy of ubuntu 10.10 so i downgraded!! to make it work!!!  I'll definitely try this.

Answer (score 1):

The menu options for the Selenium Firefox plugin version 1.7.3 and 1.9.0 appeared for me.

I used Firefox 14.0.1 to test.

- Download Selenium IDE 1.7.3 from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/
- Install and Restart
- Click `Tool` (at the top) then click `Selenium IDE`

Version 1.9.0 is available here.
http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.9.0/selenium-ide-1.9.0.xpi

If you're still having the issues, then consider creating a new firefox profile and then reinstalling Selenium.

Or you could just install using a portable version of Firefox located here.

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable/

Comment: thanks Larry.  i reinstalled version 1.7.3, but i had the same issue again.  i'll try creating new firefox profile and reinstalling.  just a quick question, may i know which OS u tested on?

Comment: @puvi Window XP. Try using the portable version of Firefox.

Comment: Thanks again Larry.  I did lil google-ing around portable version of firefox and found that it is compatible only with windows machine http://portableapps.com/about/what_is_a_portable_app.  I'll try downgrading firefox to version 10 or something.